# How to set (unix) permissions when creating a file in SAP ABAP?

Tags: unix, abap

you would think this would be obvious, but searching through documentation, SAP forums, Googling, etc., I've been spectacularly unsuccessful.  I'm creating a file in ABAP on a solaris filesystem using the following code:

```
OPEN DATASET p_file FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT.
```

the resulting file is owned and grouped according to a pre-defined admin user, which is fine, but the sticky wicket is that the permissions are set to 660/rw-rw----, meaning I can't examine the results.  is there a way (possibly using that vaguely defined TYPE addition?) I can specify the resulting permissions on the new file?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works in 4.6B:

```
        CONCATENATE 'chmod ugo=rw ' lc_filename
          INTO lc_chmod SEPARATED BY space.
        CALL 'SYSTEM' ID 'COMMAND' FIELD lc_chmod.
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Heiko

Comment: Dubious about public write; try 'ug=rw,o=r'.

Answer (score 4):

Go to SM69, create a logical system command, you could call it ZCHMOD.

Map that command to `chmod`, then call with the proper parameter
(`man chmod` on the command line is your friend).

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE'
  EXPORTING
    commandname                   = 'ZCHMOD'
    additional_parameters         = l_par
    operatingsystem               = l_os
  TABLES
    exec_protocol                 = it_log
  EXCEPTIONS
    no_permission                 = 1
    command_not_found             = 2
    parameters_too_long           = 3
    security_risk                 = 4
    wrong_check_call_interface    = 5
    program_start_error           = 6
    program_termination_error     = 7
    x_error                       = 8
    parameter_expected            = 9
    too_many_parameters           = 10
    illegal_command               = 11
    wrong_asynchronous_parameters = 12
    cant_enq_tbtco_entry          = 13
    jobcount_generation_error     = 14
    OTHERS                        = 15.
```

Obviously, that would be a 2 step process, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In RZ10 add  parameter **install/umask**. 
Default value is 007, you can change it: 000, 002...
So, the files created will be -rw-rw-rw-, -rw-rw-r--...

Comment: Greetings, you might not want this mask set for _all_ new files.